# Filtering iterables using a lambda function

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda, python-itertools

I am trying to solve [Project Euler problem 2](http://projecteuler.net/problem=2) in Python, and decided on a strategy based on iterables.

Here is the generator for the Fibonacci sequence,

```
def fnFibonacci():
    fibNumPrev, fibNumCurrent = 0, 1
    while True:
        yield fibNumCurrent
        fibNumPrev, fibNumCurrent = fibNumCurrent, fibNumCurrent + fibNumPrev
```

When I try to filter out the Fibonacci numbers that are less than 4 million and divisible by 2, it doesn't work, filtering everything out:

```
sum(list(itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x < 4e6 and x % 2 == 0 , fnFibonacci())))
```

However, both this (which ignores the evenness condition):

```
sum(list(itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x < 4e6, fnFibonacci())))
```

and this list comprehension:

```
sum([fibNum for fibNum in list(itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x < 4e6, fnFibonacci())) if fibNum % 2 == 0])
```

work. Can't really tell what's going on.

Comment: See [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/23388/4916) for a similar approach.

Comment: @DSM Wow, that is eerily like my approach. Does that mean I am a good Python programmer now? ;)

Comment: "There should be one obvious way to do it", as we say, and you found it.  You're learning the Zen. :^)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`itertools.takewhile` stops when it finds the first value that does not match the criterion. Since the first number is 1 and not divisible by 2 it stops immediately.

You can write this:

```
 sum(x for x in itertools.takewhile(lambda n: n < 4e6, fnFibonacci()) 
                if x % 2 == 0)
```